# Extern on global vector variable does not work

Tags: c++, global-variables, extern

I am trying to use vector variables as global and externing it to use it in another file, Here is my code

Header file :

```
using namespace cv;

typedef struct objectparamstruct
{
  std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;
  Mat des_object;
  char label[10];
}objectparamstruct;
```

My header file has no definition of the vector variables.

Main.cpp

```
std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
```

functions.cpp

```
extern std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
errorLNK:2005:.....already defined in functions.obj 
errorLNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

I am new to C++, could anyone please help me out here.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation. Issue resolved.

Answer (score 2):

```
extern std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
```

Is a definition, since you provide an initializer. Defining `obj_corner` multiple times in your program hurts the [odr-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). What you want instead, in order to follow the odr-rule , is a declaration:

**functions.cpp**

```
extern std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners;
```

This simply introduces the object's name `obj_corners` to your translation unit, telling the linker that it is defined in another translation unit ( main.cpp in this case ).

Answer (score 1):

The definition should look like this:

```
 std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
```

and the extern declaration like this:

```
 extern std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners;
```

The first statement is actually using a constructor to create the vector, while the second statement simply says the vector exists somewhere.